# Host multiple sites on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I am trying to host multiple sites on local for development by using [this](http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/03/setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-apache-on-ubuntu-for-local-development/) tutorial, but after configuration I get error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.2.20
>   (Ubuntu) Server at test.local Port 80

Can someone help me to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is there something in you logfiles?

```
###> cd /var/log/apache2/
root@e520:/var/log/apache2
###> ls -ltr
```

The last file is the most recent one. Look at it:

less error.log  (Then press G (big g)) or use tail -f ...

I guess you don't have a "index.html" file in your document root. If you don't allow directory listing, you get a permission denied error.